# Can i have a component stay mounted while passing it to another?

Tags: reactjs

I have something like this:

```
{condition ? (
  <Bar/>
) : (
  <Foo/>
)
```

Inside of `<Bar/>`

```
return (
  <>
   <A/>
   <B/>
   <Foo/> 
   <C/>
  </>
)
```

So it's really just a flat list of components before and after foo. While switching the condition, the whole thing unmounts.

```
{condition ? (
  <Bar>
   {memoizedFoo}
  </Bar>
) : (
  memoizedFoo
)}
```

Does not work unfortunately :/ but thats sort of what i want.
How could i achieve this, or refactor the code considering that `<Bar/>` has gazillion effects and promises and stuff, **but its a single prop that it passes to `<Foo/>`**?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
const [cProps, setCProps] = useState(null as any)
{condition && <Bar setCProps={setCProps}/>}
<Foo/>
{condition && <C ...cProps/>}
```

Which feels very anti patterny, so if there is a better answer it's more than welcome. In the meantime this seems to work. A lot of effects and memoized things were happening in bar, but in the end only a handful of results are written so i bundled those.